# Criar executável python: PyOS_InputHook is not available for interactive use of PyGTK

Tags: python, instalador

Eu recém terminei meu primeiro programa com python e gostaria de criar um executável para distribuição.
Contudo, estou tendo dificuldade em fazer isso. Eu já tentei usar **py2exe**, **pyinstaller** e **cx_freeze** sem sucesso. Depois de ler muitas opiniões a respeito, eu acredito que a melhor solução para meu caso seja usar o **pyinstaller**, mas eu não estou conseguindo fazer o arquivo .exe que ele cria funcionar.

Os imports que eu faço em meu programa estão abaixo:

```
import os
import pygtk
import gtk
import MySQLdb
import getpass as gt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas.io import sql
from scipy import stats, integrate
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn import metrics
```

Lendo a documentação do **pyinstaller** eu vi que as única `libs` que ele não suporta são `scikit-learn` (`sklearn`) e `seaborn`. Quando eu uso `pyinstaller --onefile Principal.py` é criado a pasta dist e build, mas quando eu tento rodar o arquivo .exe eu recebo a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> C:\Users\Lucas\AppData\Local\Temp_MEI82242\gtk__init__.py:127: RuntimeWarning:
>        PyOS_InputHook is not available for interactive use of PyGTK
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "", line 13, in 
>         File "c:\users\lucas\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-6fpfyh\pyinstaller\PyInstall
>       er\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 363, in load_module
>         File "c:\users\lucas\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas__init__.py", line 13,
>       in 
>           "extensions first.".format(module))
>       ImportError: C extension: lib not built. If you want to import pandas from the s
>       ource directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace' to bu
>       ild the C extensions first.
>       Principal returned -1

Alguém pode me dar uma luz de como fazer isso?

Comment: No erro diz: > you may need to run '`python setup.py build_ext --inplace`' Você já tentou rodar este comando?

Comment: Já tentei sim, mas o que seria o arquivo setup.py? Porque para o pyinstaller não precisa criar um arquivo setup como o py2exe.

Comment: Só gostaria de deixar comentado que se seu programa é para usuarios um pouco mais do que leigo você pode simplesmente pedir para ele baixar o python e executar um  script de instalação o famoso setup.py, muitos programas são distibuidos assim. Se for também para usuarios Ubuntu/Fedora é mais facil ainda.

Answer (score 1):

Retirado diretamente de uma [issue](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1580) do repositório do [pyinstaller](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller):

> fixed this issue on my end. Pyinstaller wasn't including $PYTHONDIR/site-packages/pandas/lib.so` just copied this into the dist directory and named it pandas.lib.so and it appears to be working. Pyinstaller is awesome keep up the good work!

Trocando em miúdos, copie o arquivo que a linha 13 do **pandas__init__.py** está pedindo, no caso, o arquivo **lib.so** em *$PYTHONDIR/site-packages/pandas/*, e copie pro seu diretório **dist**.

De acordo com a abertura da issue, o carinha usa também Windows, e isso pode diminuir as possibilidades de não ser efetivo tal solução, visto que o autor da pergunta também possui o mesmo cenário, ou bem próximo disso :)